# Nvim Dap produces error on Mac OS when running debugger on Rust code

Tags: rust, neovim

I am having a problem trying to debug rust with Neovim on a Macbook Air M2 with Ventura 13.1 installed.

I have already installed llvm by `brew install llvm` and VSCode is also installed, where the extension CodeLLDB is active. In my Mac, this is found with the following path: `/Users/jj/.vscode/extensions/vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.8.1/adapter/codelldb`

Then, I tried to follow the instructions as best I could from [here](https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap/wiki/C-C---Rust-(via--codelldb)) to get this to work.

Under Packer I have the following installed:

```
    use("mfussenegger/nvim-dap")
    use({
        "rcarriga/nvim-dap-ui",
        requires = {
            "mfussenegger/nvim-dap",
            "theHamsta/nvim-dap-virtual-text",
            "nvim-telescope/telescope-dap.nvim",
        },
    })

    use("simrat39/rust-tools.nvim")
```

Part of my init.lua file is the following:

```
require("dap").adapters.codelldb = {
  type = "server",
  port = "${port}",
  executable = {
    command = "/Users/jj/.vscode/extensions/vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.8.1/adapter/codelldb",
    args = { "--port", "${port}" },
},
}

require("dap").configurations.rust = {
{
  name = "Launch file",
  type = "codelldb",
  request = "launch",
  program = function()
    return vim.fn.input("Path to executable: ", vim.fn.getcwd() .. "/", "file")
  end,
  cwd = "${workspaceFolder}",
  stopOnEntry = false,
},
}

require("nvim-dap-virtual-text").setup()
require("dapui").setup()

local dap, dapui = require("dap"), require("dapui")
dap.listeners.after.event_initialized["dapui_config"] = function()
    dapui.open()
end
dap.listeners.before.event_terminated["dapui_config"] = function()
    dapui.close()
end
dap.listeners.before.event_exited["dapui_config"] = function()
    dapui.close()
end

require("rust-tools").setup({
    tools = {
        executor = require("rust-tools.executors").termopen,
        reload_workspace_from_cargo_toml = true,

        inlay_hints = {
            lifetimeElisionHints = {
                enable = true,
                useParameterNames = true,
            },
            auto = true,
            only_current_line = true,
            show_parameter_hints = true,
            parameter_hints_prefix = "<- ",
            other_hints_prefix = "-> ",
        },
    },

    server = {
        capabilities = capabilities,
        on_attach = on_attach,
        standalone = true,

        settings = {
            ["rust-analyzer"] = {
                assist = {
                    importPrefix = "by_self",
                },
                cargo = {
                    allFeatures = true,
                },
                checkOnSave = {
                    command = "clippy",
                },
                lens = {
                    references = true,
                    methodReferences = true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    
    dap = {
    adapter = require("dap").adapters.codelldb,
    },
})
```

Then, when I run the debugger, it allows me to toggle breakpoints, and then tries to start up, but then gives me the following error:

```
[debug-adapter stderr] [2023-01-11T14:49:13.755Z ERROR codelldb::debug_session] '/Users/jj' doesn't contain any 'host' platform architectures: arm64, armv7, armv7f, armv7k, armv7s, armv7m, armv7em, armv6m, armv6, armv5, armv4, arm, thumbv7, thumbv7k, thumbv7s, thumbv7f, thumbv7m, thumbv7em, thumbv6m, thumbv6, thumbv5, thumbv4t, thumb, x86_64, x86_64, arm64, arm64e, arm64, arm64e
```

Maybe something is wrong with the lua config, but I have searched everything and still can't find anything that fixes this.

Then, if I try and use the rust-tools command "RustDebuggables" it gives me a response of `Resolved locations: 0` and then it says the following:

```
Debug adapter didn't respond. Either the adapter is slow (then wait and ignore this) or there is a problem with your adapter or `rt_lldb` configuration. Check the logs for errors (:help dap.set_log_level)
```

I really don't know what else to put to make this work. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap/wiki/Debug-Adapter-installation#ccrust-via-lldb-vscode

Have you checked this?